# Webcrawling with selenium couldn't extract the XPath of a button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, web-crawler

I want to automate a data collection process of the Open Data BDAP (Italian public projects) and the website of target is https://bdap-opendata.rgs.mef.gov.it/opendata/spd_mop_sog_mon_reg01_01_9999?t=Scarica
I would like to crawl into this website iterating every time on a Italian region 'reg01' +1 (until 20)
I have succeeded to crawl into the website but the download button on the CSV file is no where to be found.
Could you please help me identify what's the issue?

Here is the code:

```py
import sys
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

# default tripadvisor website of hotel or things to do (attraction/monument) 
url = "https://bdap-opendata.rgs.mef.gov.it/opendata/spd_mop_prg_mon_reg18_01_9999?t=Scarica"

# import the webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Excel file format.']").click()

driver.quit()
```

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@title='Excel file format.']"}
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.64)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because after the page loaded it fetches data using JavaScript. That means when Selenium thinks the page is already fully loaded it is in fact not.

The solution to this is to add a sleep statement right before you try to click the button. 5-10 seconds should be good but if your internet is slow you might need to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're getting `NoSuchElementException` error is because the element you're trying to locate resides inside an `iframe` which can not be located without switching to it.

here's the complete solution:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://bdap-opendata.rgs.mef.gov.it/opendata/spd_mop_prg_mon_reg18_01_9999?t=Scarica"

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# wait for the target iframe to get loaded in order to switch to it
iframe = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe.tabIframe.dinamically-tab-iframe-content')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@title="Excel file format."]'))).click()

try:
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
except NoAlertPresentException:
    pass

time.sleep(5)
```

Steps to follow:

1. First wait for the desired `iframe` tag to be get loaded/located on the page.
2. after making sure that it's loaded, switch to this `iframe` as mentioned in the code above (using `switch_to.frame()`)
3. Once you're inside the `iframe`, you can easily locate the desired element using XPATH but make sure it is clickable before clicking as the website takes some time to load this particular section on the page.
4. Sometimes, when you click the desired button/element, an alert box appears as shown below, you can simply accept it:

[image: alert box]

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Ajeet Verma's answer is perfect, just follow the code in his answer, you should be able to get rid of `NoSuchElementException`.

There is one more issue I would like to point out. As per your question, you want to click on download CSV button. But your XPath expression is locating the download Excel button. And moreover, your XPath is locating 2 elements.

***I have succeeded to crawl into the website but the download button on the CSV file is no where to be found***

Refer the below XPath expressions:

```
# If you want to click on Dato Filtrato button of Export Excel
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),"Dato Filtrato") and @data-value="xls_complete"]'))).click()

# If you want to click on Dato Filtrato button of Export CSV
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),"Dato Filtrato") and @data-value="csv"]'))).click()

# If you want to click on Dato Completo button of Export Excel
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),"Dato Filtrato") and @data-value="xls_complete"]'))).click()

# If you want to click on Dato Completo button of Export CSV
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(),"Dato Filtrato") and @data-value="csv"]'))).click()
```